# Load a component inside modal and pass data back

Tags: modal-dialog, components, angular-cli, pass-data

I have a component A which has a button that launches a modal dialog that renders component B. In the modal dialog the user can take some action in component b and I want a value from component b to be accessible in component A when dialog dismisses.

## a.component.html

```
<ng-template #lookupCustomerDialog let-modal>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <app-component-b></app-component-b>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

when user dismisses the dialog above I want a value from app-component-b to be available in component a

Answer (score 2):

I'm using EventEmitter to solve this:

A.Component.ts

```
export class ComponentA implements OnInit {
    sampleFuncInAComponent(data: any) {
        /*your codes that using data from component b*/
    }
}
```

B.Component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
export class ComponentA implements OnInit {
    @Output() sendDataEvent = new EventEmitter();
    myData;
    onSendDataFunc() {
        this.sendDataEvent.emit(this.myData);
    }
}
```

A.Component.html

```
<ng-template #lookupCustomerDialog let-modal>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <app-component-b (sendDataEvent)="sampleFuncInAComponent($event)"></app-component-b>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I tried that, but it returns a reference to the modal dialog #lookupCustomerDialog. I want a reference to the component rendered inside the dialog which is rendered as <app-component-b></app-component-b>